# How to extract concrete data from a column of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to extract data from one column based on another, an example will be clearer.

in one column I have direction data (0º - 360º), and in another I have wind speed data, so for example I want to know the average wind speed in a northerly direction (360º) for this I want for all 360º values ​​in the direction column extract the corresponding data in the speed column. so to be able to calculate the average, as the sum of the speed / frequency

I know that with the df.drop function I can put conditions and eliminate the rows that meet it, would there be a function that allows me to extract those rows

If someone comes up with a method to extract this data according to each address, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Please add example rows from the real or mock data frame. Then post the desired output. Explain us what you have tried to get to the output based on the input. Otherwise you might not get any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is the `groupby` method.

Assuming that:

- your dataframe is named `df`
- your direction column is called `direction`
- your wind speed column is called `wind_speed`...

...you can simply run:

```
df.groupby('direction').mean()['wind_speed']
```

...to compute the average wind speed for each direction in the `direction` column.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
import pandas as pd

#sample DF
df = pd.DataFrame({'direction': [0, 45, 90, 135, 180, 225, 270, 315, 360],
                   'speed': [5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45]})

# extract rows where direction is 360
df_360 = df.loc[df['direction'] == 360, ['speed']]

# calculate the mean wind speed in a northerly direction
mean_speed = df_360['speed'].mean()

print(mean_speed)  # prints 45.0
```

is it helpful ?